# Delete AWS S3 Object using Nodejs Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to delete AWS S3 Object according to the time of creation using Nodejs Lambda function. I want to delete all objects in a particular folder which are created before 24 hour 
Now I have tried to delete multiple object which is success but I dnt know how to do it with time

```
var params = {
      Bucket: s3bucket, 
      Delete: { 
        Objects: [ 
          {
            Key: 'scheduled_lambda_test/1.png' 
          },
          {
            Key: 'scheduled_lambda_test/2.png' 
          }
        ]
      }
    };

s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: @LorenaSalamanca I have updated my question Plz check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use node sdk and perform below operations

1. use listObject action on your folder.
2. Loop through all the object returned for that folder and check last modified date.
3. If object is expired add object key to an array.
4. Delete all the object in expired array

Node SDK Doc - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html