# How to remove the corresponding thumbnails from subdirectories in case the image was deleted from the S3 bucket root?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm Using AWS S3 service for media purpose and also using AWS Lamda services for thumb related images.

Facing the following issue: if I remove media in the main directory than the thumbnails (generated by Lambda) will still exist in the sub-directories.

For example: 
If I remove "1513928090496_juCQtDAt6ylr.jpg" file from Node.js code than I also need the same file to be deleted from "100x100","1920x720" and "300x300" directories. (They also contain same file "1513928090496_juCQtDAt6ylr.jpg")

For more details please refer [image]uploaded image.

Comment: Please check, it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715682/delete-aws-s3-object-using-nodejs-lambda-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use an another Lambda function.
You can trigger it's execution when an object is deleted from the bucket.

The function will then analyze if the deleted object was located in the root directory and if so - delete the thumbnails from the subfolders.

Here is the function which you could use:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const thumbnailFolders = ["100x100", "1920x720", "300x300"];

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const bucketName = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const deletedFileKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  // If there are no forward slashes the file was in the root folder.
  const wasInRootDirectory = !deletedFileKey.includes("/");
  if (!wasInRootDirectory) {
    // If if was not in the root foler, ignore it.
    return;
  }

  const thumbnailsToDelete = thumbnailFolders.map(f => {
    return { Key: `${f}/${deletedFileKey}` };
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Delete: {
      Objects: thumbnailsToDelete
    }
  };

  s3.deleteObjects(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      callback(err);
      return;
    }

    //Deleted successfully
    callback();
  });
};
```

In order to run your lambda on object deletion, you need to set up the trigger in AWS Console (go to your Lambda -> Configuring):

[image]

Also you should make sure that your Lamda's role has a Policy that allows it to delete objects from the bucket.

In my case I added an inline Policy like this:

[image]

So it generated the following Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::thumbnails-bucket-123",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```